# Histogram frequency

Tags: r, histogram

I have a data set of about 1000 data points (values ranging from 987 to 61,515) and I'm trying to create a histogram with the probability density function instead of frequency.

I tried changing "freq = FALSE" or "prob = TRUE" but in both case I get the wrong %

```
hist(data1000, freq = FALSE)
```

I expect my Y-axis to show the density (0.0 to 1.0), but the actual y-axis has values of 0.00001 to 0.000015

Is there a way for me to upload the figure of my output, I believe this will make my question clearer?

here is my data set:

```
data= c(18124,12957,10232,19156,22015,14467,9812,36416,9530,6848,12029,20201,21787,19953,17698,14217,14771,22480,11063,31452,22196,2580,12973,8020,6632,19522,12047,7544,61515,12929,8623,10485,12612,10461,14014,8986,19864,12554,8071,14428,6924,11808,14238,16718,41123,23910,3615,13130,32555,14860,22347,8288,10390,18384,5542,41845,14156,5391,15015,14515,11571,20426,29791,10785,10820,18001,18291,11912,13037,24351,18694,13024,18185,12200,8025,10229,12218,6802,14127,10215,5582,3480,6691,25749,28012,24980,31255,10864,16890,5863,11369,1967,10232,14748,14943,8201,14804,15001,19112,21836,7309,9612,16788,13326,24983,16130,8633,22003,7272,12709,14404,23135,10758,43422,9859,6864,28675,21013,7879,6600,16426,15693,18225,13613,14643,32442,21591,23613,17259,17336,6127,20072,12419,5396,9371,8326,24437,10195,13930,35118,13303,10922,10452,11841,21410,9812,21312,7599,11719,11921,20493,19485,29040,13880,10618,22020,13143,8529,15380,9287,18536,25477,27116,14826,17309,18272,12793,19918,21231,10824,8421,30132,12006,17623,23309,25103,29187,12886,23328,23889,20766,14943,29909,23986,8476,17588,14565,13592,19408,36739,13488,11929,38903,7608,47485,10201,28221,30662,19382,27255,27029,22341,18261,50145,27973,49933,30022,37339,9482,9696,25198,9322,37734,10881,5165,11176,27707,29747,25769,18764,35669,40017,28801,23393,11792,25543,17552,45900,12135,11495,37428,19765,7205,24715,36810,13453,11273,12044,16910,23625,52021,17858,8571,15845,12432,26575,20768,28757,36219,19871,14319,15865,18824,13871,26157,16520,18385,43970,27882,15761,10565,30181,18972,10325,16724,25191,18755,23134,3517,13794,9422,11078,32387,15043,14587,18243,29831,22846,15758,14534,22022,19180,18598,18037,22183,29266,53410,19083,9519,20478,15904,14385,18483,13672,9530,11101,19891,9984,12445,8872,12720,8277,3878,6569,11947,19384,9258,7090,8456,9313,9752,14374,13182,31067,20905,9420,8137,9005,14460,21410,11236,47406,13247,15373,28414,23889,9384,21116,19878,32668,18491,15016,26640,28870,14505,18009,38628,11889,13065,19236,35277,13639,14950,25448,23388,6886,8888,23417,21360,24183,19521,14651,28611,15705,16157,16458,17386,17428,16370,14609,8791,14463,18153,5586,8806,14305,17216,16793,22897,16598,8837,32668,11741,11761,10826,15865,19805,10252,19258,17174,7874,7581,22427,8549,25789,20059,23891,19380,11138,17154,16622,12423,9652,13072,27632,20082,20308,11614,13287,6746,21413,16531,15557,12108,21136,22857,6950,17734,42772,20374,14177,24593,14897,8064,23842,15699,21295,24693,20505,12341,20239,16609,15061,20737,23763,15882,10423,16354,22338,18082,24631,12607,22930,9116,41550,11874,32281,18024,17641,19413,17550,6997,13388,6709,11070,10751,19738,8461,14106,11309,18259,14254,19457,15169,16567,15991,17634,27156,15566,11907,12449,15437,21896,12022,17617,10018,20314,11880,17745,22766,15548,19714,11118,13958,16392,8108,31388,13406,17098,20208,32396,13931,15951,11869,15222,29971,9054,21628,7601,13030,17674,47025,16801,12934,23975,14908,11504,11207,15692,9028,7502,6879,15785,15375,8033,15774,5761,14715,23413,17876,18937,12706,17326,14689,8155,14753,23087,10946,9761,17078,13083,14374,13550,26252,17484,14779,15608,17504,28028,15012,10773,13944,4210,17535,11707,20923,18299,8341,20755,21588,17056,5158,9001,11628,15787,21561,14259,11304,14782,8744,4616,3701,5557,8188,6139,8348,6600,17612,7674,4850,8757,4239,11920,9887,16467,9885,9617,6361,7134,11003,11455,10573,23016,9674,2270,9931,3479,8726,6219,1754,2186,8427,3174,3657,3061,20212,14538,12810,7103,2184,8806,7211,6077,11269,6294,19041,1568,10383,7847,3761,11171,10425,15267,15685,10930,2321,11362,11761,7240,5590,3610,12881,5156,15220,8425,7320,13014,7236,10219,4060,10886,8591,12144,7349,10934,9313,3477,6631,14469,18819,12401,3331,4569,4538,4029,7377,5588,10587,13074,10226,9568,15504,13134,9063,6828,7614,4201,5690,9125,7763,994,8226,7003,8582,7716,6593,7455,3874,3329,5442,4091,7079,10472,6246,10155,4844,5149,3161,5863,5843,11231,3451,6093,7652,8726,9032,7245,6664,10312,6325,3745,7369,5019,6658,8144,8150,14693,14622,11504,10095,2295,5942,3508,8959,5619,9515,8844,5453,4414,16870,2235,7809,6861,11506,9191,6673,5105,6748,6379,5245,16502,12031,4711,6286,13222,7670,5758,988,9725,8416,6157,10693,10748,6928,3581,3759,5231,3659,4018,6042,7059,4184,7650,9856,6569,10243,7765,3156,6791,4053,6673,6762,10939,7234,8558,7225,5612,6035,8204,5743,7907,8317,3827,4007,3878,6589,5734,15092,7346,12804,10235,8997,9344,7154,21202,4044,4507,7172,3801,6022,3785,5023,6100,13140,2804,5714,7103,5285,16365,5646,6334,8317,12188,9105,10312,5025,5548,13098,2941,3094,4777,4943,4917,10480,11570,18584,10354,8511,7787,5123,6983,8576,11825,17036,7863,6232,4888,6587,17324,10678,6567,7530,9674,7245,9657,2764,9707,3223,9599,7953,4031,7962,10534,13419,4219,11942,6917,6773,5123,4910,3067,5942,7249,9583,12064,10837,10177,7167,7087,12616,13267,9211,10394,10126,14166,17656,13198,13785,9389,7967,10912,3958,6569,8418,8751,5083,17725,22786,23665,12153,23147,16485,8150,6536,31840)
```

Update - June 20, 2019

when I try to force the # of bins (and consequently get higher distribution values) I  get an error message.

This is the command -

```
hist(data, 
     breaks = c(5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000, 
                35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000, 60000), 
     freq = FALSE)
```

and this is the message:

> Error in hist.default(CrOsAr865, breaks = c(5000, 10000, 15000, 20000,  : 
>     some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'

Comment: Though probability density functions sum to 1, they do not reach 1 on a plot (only on rare occurrences when the entire distributions in a given range). If you'd like to group the graphic together better, you could use hist(data,breaks=10) or something (play with the amount of breaks).

Comment: I think you need to show more of what you have done. I tried `hist(iris[,1])` which showed the histogram with counts and then `hist(iris[,1], freq=F)` and it showed the probability density as desired.

Comment: `hist(runif(1e3), prob = TRUE)` gives an y axis from 0 to 0.9; `hist(rnorm(1e3), prob = TRUE)` from 0 to 0.4; `hist(rcauchy(1e3), prob = TRUE)` from 0 to 0.0025. Can you see where this is going?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The density values on the y-axis are correct. The area under the density function should equal one, but that does not mean that your y-axis will be from 0-1. Your data has a standard deviation of 8601.927, so your distribution is stretched out, and the probability of any individual value on the x-axis is exceedingly small. To illustrate we can generate some normal distributions with varying SDs:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

tibble(`SD = 1` = rnorm(1000, 1000, 1),
       `SD = 10` = rnorm(1000, 1000, 10),
       `SD = 100` = rnorm(1000, 1000, 100),
       `SD = 1000` = rnorm(1000, 1000, 1000),
       ) %>% 
    gather(labs, vals) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = vals)) + 
    geom_density() + 
    facet_wrap(~ labs, scales = "free")
```

[image]

The y-scale decreases because the data is being stretched. It's a little weird because the distributions look so similar on different y-scales, but if we look at them on the same scale we can see how they become increasingly stretched out (note that I've changed the SDs to highlight the change in shape):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, a density plot/histogram has an area equal to 1. You can easily see that with your example by capturing the output of the hist() function:

```
out <- hist(data, freq=FALSE)
sum(out$density)
# [1] 0.0002
sum(out$density) * 5000
# [1] 1
```

out is a list with 6 parts. out$density contains the density values shown on the y-axis. Their sum is only .0002. To get the area of the histogram we need to multiply the density values by the width of the bars. Looking at out$breaks we can see that each bar is 5000 units wide. When we multiply the densities by the width, the sum is 1.